# Pinch zoom in fl_charts

Tags: flutter, dart

I am just new to Flutter and mobile dev overall, so I've tried to create some Line Chart using fl_chart and there is a problem, which I don't understand why it doesn't work.

So, here is a simple widget, which has a chart and I want to add some interactions to it like a horizontal scroll (it works), reset the state with a double-tap (works as well), and the ability to zoom in to the chart (doesn't work).

Gesture Detector has onScaleUpdate, which I thought it's what I need, but when I try to pinch-zoom in or out, the callback is not being called and I can't change the chart. A lot of things were tried, in order to make it work, but it was unsuccessful.

```
import 'package:fl_chart/fl_chart.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
// ...
class FlChartState extends State<FlChart> {
  List<LineChartBarData> mainChartData = [];
  double minX = 0;
  double maxX = 0;
  double resultsLength = 60;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _mainBarDataCalculation(); // Method that prepares the data for the chart
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onDoubleTap: () {
        setState(() {
          minX = 0;
          maxX = resultsLength;
        });
      },
      onScaleUpdate: (scaleUpd) {
        // doesn't trigger
      },
      onHorizontalDragUpdate: (dragUpdDet) {
        setState(() {
          double primDelta = dragUpdDet.primaryDelta ?? 0.0;
          if (primDelta != 0) {
            if (primDelta.isNegative) {
              if (maxX < resultsLength) {
                minX += maxX * 0.005;
                maxX += maxX * 0.005;
              }
            } else {
              if (minX > 0) {
                minX -= maxX * 0.005;
                maxX -= maxX * 0.005;
              }
            }
          }
        });
      },
      child: LineChart(_createLineChartDataWidget()),
    );
  }

  // ...
}
```

Is there something wrong?

Comment: Can you add the Logcat or Error message to to figure out what's the wrong

Comment: I don't see any errors in the console or on the devices (I'm running the app on Samsung S10). Everything seems fine, but the function for onScaleUpdate (even for onScaleStart) is not being triggered

Comment: When you click on zoom, what's happen, can you see what shows on logcat or try to use breakpoints to trigger where is the problem .. Hope you find the solution